# How to lock designable size of custom UView

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard, uicontrol

I am making a custom activityIndicator. I wanted it to behave like `UIActivityIndicatorView` but with different animations.

When you place `UIActivityIndicatorView` to Storyboard the width and height of this view are locked for modification (grayed out).

There is no problem to make fixed width for the view in code but
is it possible to make custom view the same way `UIActivityIndicatorView` is made: with width and height grayed out in storyboard?

Comment: Can you add you code work to show how you are creating activity indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Thorax, good day!

Well, i found an answer for your question [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4108)!

Though it was 1.5 year ago, i don't think that something had changed

Comment: Thank you, Eugene, there still may be an answer out there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to grayed out width and height, but there is a way to avoid setting width and height constrains all the time in IB: you should just override intrinsicContentSize() in your UIView subclass.
In Swift for example:

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50)
}
```